# WIX installer: Use property value to place a file

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3

I've read a property from the registry, and that property has been set properly (I'm using this to check the property value)

```
<CustomAction Id="Test" Script="vbscript">
   <![CDATA[MsgBox Session.Property("MYEXTRAFILESFOLDER")]]>
</CustomAction>
```

Now I'm just trying to drop a few files into that folder. I can't figure out how to make a File element target a specific directory.

Comment: I think you need to play with Session.TargetPath method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I get you don't need to change taget path in general but only put some files to specific folder. Easiest way is to create [custom action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54144994/how-to-create-custom-actions-in-c-sharp-and-bind-it-on-a-wix-setup-project).

1. Add custom action as [described](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54144994/how-to-create-custom-actions-in-c-sharp-and-bind-it-on-a-wix-setup-project)
2. In InstallExecuteSequence set After=InstallFiles or After=InstallFinalize (to make sure that your files from installer will be copied already)
3. In custom action [read you path from registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56182272/how-to-read-registry-data-from-c-sharp)
4. [Get you install path using TARGETDIR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1824891/wix-passing-install-path-to-managed-custom-action)
5. Move files from [TargetDir to your registry dir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13621975/move-files-in-c-sharp)

Another option is

1. Create custom action as described
2. In custom action [read you path from registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56182272/how-to-read-registry-data-from-c-sharp)
3. [Get file stream from installer and write it to folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35743982/wix-how-to-access-source-file-from-custom-action)

[Also this can be an option too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9564497/copy-possible-files-to-location-with-msi-custom-action). But I don't know how it works exactly